# R sqldf package Month function

Tags: mysql, r, sqldf

I'm trying to use native sql functions within `sqldf` such as `month`. I am not sure why this doesn't work. There is monthly data in the dataframe which I am pulling from so I don't understand. If I subset it in dbGetQuery, then it works since it is pulling directly from the MySQL database, but when I try to do the same with the `sqldf` package it fails.

```
sqldf("select * from data_old_cust where month(order_date) = 1", drv = 'SQLite')
```

> Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) :    error in
>   statement: no such function: month

Answer (score 2):

By default sqldf uses SQLite via the RSQLite driver R package and `month` is not a function supported by SQLite nor is it one of the extension functions supported by RSQLite.  There are some examples of processing dates on the sqldf home page https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf and there is information on SQLite date functions here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html and from these resources you can find other functions.

If you use sqldf with the H2 database supported by the RH2 R package then `month` is supported.  For example,

```
library(RH2)
library(sqldf)
DF <- data.frame(d = as.Date("2000-08-15"))

sqldf("select month(d) from DF")
```

giving:

```
   MONTH("d")
 1          8
```